# s3.putObject not working when `Key` contains special characters

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am encountering an issue while using the s3.putObject function in my AWS Lambda function. The problem arises specifically when the Key parameter of the putObject call contains special characters. It seems that the function fails to upload the object to the specified S3 bucket when the Key contains characters such as symbols, spaces, or non-alphanumeric characters.

I noticed that when the Key does not contain any special characters, the s3.putObject function works as expected. However, when special characters are present, the function fails to upload the object.

I have tried different variations of the Key value, including URL encoding the special characters, but the issue persists. I have also made sure that I have the necessary permissions for the S3 bucket and that the bucket name and region are correctly specified.

I'm wondering if there are any specific considerations or restrictions regarding the use of special characters in the Key parameter of the s3.putObject function. Additionally, I would appreciate any insights or workarounds that could help me resolve this issue.

Here is a simplified example of the code I am using:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const key = 'Folder(FA)/subfolder/text.jpg' failed
// const key = 'Folder_FA/subfolder/text.jpg' working

const params = {
  Bucket: 'my-bucket',
  Key: key,
  Body: 'Some data'
};

s3.putObject(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Successfully uploaded object to S3');
  }
});
```

I have tried different variations of the `Key` value in the `s3.putObject` function. Specifically, I attempted to URL encode the special characters in the `Key` parameter.

I was expecting the `s3.putObject` function to successfully upload the object to the specified S3 bucket, regardless of whether the `Key` contained special characters.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html - parenthesis should be fine without any additional handling, other characters might require special handling. What error do you get for what exact key names?

Comment: These are the exact key names:
"VirginAustralia(VA)/lufthansa_mpd/VA_202309_YoungSheldon-S6Ep1/Manifest.mpd"
It's peculiar that when I checked in CloudWatch, there was no success or error message. The system simply skipped that line.

Comment: This simplified code example you posted works fine. I just tested it. Hard to tell without actual example - perhaps there are some invisible characters in your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

According to Amazon's documentation on [creating object key names:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html):

1. Object key name length should be 1-1024 characters
2. Object keys are UTF-8 encoded and can include most Unicode characters. However, AWS recommends using only printable ASCII characters
3. Object keys are case-sensitive. For example, "myObject" and "MyObject" are considered as two distinct keys
4. You can use any printable UTF-8 characters except:

   - Backslash ("")
   - Left curly brace ("{")
   - Caret ("^")
   - Non-printable ASCII characters (128–255 decimal characters)
   - Right curly brace ("}")
   - Percent character ("%")
   - Grave accent / back tick ("`")
   - Right square bracket ("]")
   - Quotation marks
   - 'Greater Than' symbol (">")
   - Left square bracket ("[")
   - Tilde ("~")
   - 'Less Than' symbol ("<")
   - 'Pound' character ("#")
   - Vertical bar / pipe ("|")
5. Some characters have reserved meanings in S3, such as question mark ("?") and ampersand ("&"), and should be [used carefully in object keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html#:%7E:text=Characters%20that%20might%20require%20special%20handling)
6. It is advisable to choose key names that are human-readable, unique, and descriptive. Avoid using sensitive or personally identifiable information as part of the key

Comment: Forward slash "/" is the default path separator used in keys. It is a _very common_ character to use in S3 keys. Your statement that they should be avoided in keys is really strange, and I can't find anything about your point number 4 in the documentation you linked, and that link even shows lots of valid example keys that use `/` characters. Your answer also leaves out a lot of "Characters to avoid" from that documentation.

Comment: @MarkB, thanks for helping me improve my answer